# Stop reoccurring Jenkins Job automatically after some time

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'd like to start a pipeline job manually. This job should then run daily and after seven days stop automatically. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK There is no OOB solution for this. But you can implement something with Groovy to achieve what you need. For example, check the following pipeline. In the below Pipeline, I'm adding a Cron expression to run every day if manually triggered and then removing the corn expression after a predefined number of runs elapse. You should be able to fine-tune the below and achieve what you need.

```
def expression = getCron()

pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers{ cron(expression) }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Build"
                }
           }
        }
    }
}

def getCron() {
    
    def runEveryDayCron = "0 9 * * *" //Runs everyday at 9
    def numberOfRunsToCheck = 7 // Will run 7 times
    
    def currentBuildNumber = currentBuild.getNumber()
    def job = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME)
   
    for(int i=currentBuildNumber; i > currentBuildNumber - numberOfRunsToCheck; i--) {
        def build = job.getBuildByNumber(i)
        if(build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause) != null) { //This is a manually triggered Build
            return runEveryDayCron
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! I eventually ended up using a remote github repository to save the state of the job (how many times it already ran etc.) and I just let the job run daily, read the state and act depending on it (either do nothing or execute some job).